# Debug an executable file with dive into its libraries in radare2

Tags: debugging, shared-libraries, radare2

I have an executable ELF file e.g. `aaa`. This executable file uses its library e.g. `../bin/libaaa.so`. When I debug `r2 -d aaa` I see some call functions from the library `libaaa.so` e.g. `sym.imp.AAAfunc1` at 0x44651.
When I reach that call, I can only step over it. How can I deep dive into `libaaa.so` file to debug that function contents?

I am new to radare2, and if some other tools can do this I can switch to that